# How to manage a failed data validation in WPF?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I have a binding with data validation implemented by IDataErrorInfo. When data validation fails, the property is set. How could I avoid the change of the property when data validation fails?
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think `IDataErrorInfo` can be used to avoid the property value change if value is not valid. It only helps binding proper error message to the `UI` so that the user can change given value to valid value.

To avoid invalid values being set in your properties, if they are `CLR Properties`, use validation methods in setters and if they are `Dependency Properties`, use validation callback to properly validate the values.